# pickadate.js, disable dates from php array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to disable dates in the pickadate.js calendar with an array I have passed from my controller (using Laravel4).

I can disable the date just fine by sending a static date to the javascript from the controller (using Jeffrey Ways great PHP-vars-to-JS):

```
JavaScript::put([
        'disabledDates' => array(2014,6,20)
        ]);
```

My .js file:

```
        disable: [
        [2014,7,19],
        [2014,7,12],
        disabledDates
    ],
```

However, this only disables the first date, and if I try to pass multiple dates into my array, only they don't get disabled in the calendar. I tried doing the following:

```
JavaScript::put([
        'disabledDates' => array(2014,6,20, 2014,6,21)
        ]);
```

The pickadate.js script only accepts the above format for disabling dates, and I think this conflicts with the way the array would ideally be built?

Can anyone help me with the correct format for this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So then, the first one works right?, i mean this: `'disabledDates' => array(2014,6,20)`

Comment: Hey Robert, 
Yes, that works! However, I cannot input multiple dates that way, since it only accepts the first part.

Comment: If you use the second way, and put in the javascript console: `disabledDates` what is the output?

Comment: It outputs the following:

    [2014, 6, 20, 2014, 6, 20]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A followup here as I managed to solve the problem with the help from a friend:

The approach is:

In my controller:

```
    $dates = Booking::lists('date');

    JavaScript::put([
        'disabledDates' => $dates
    ]);
```

In my model:

```
    public function getDateAttribute($value)
    {
    return explode('-', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value)));
    }
```

This returns the dates as an array that the calendar can then use. Hope this is helpful to anyone out there :).